# Filter method doesn't work on application hosted on IIS7, Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: jquery

Here is the example code I'm using. The purpose here is to remove undefined/null/empty strings from `strs`.

```
var strs = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
var filteredValues = strs.filter(function(s) { return s; });
```

1) If the application is hosted on Windows server 2008 R2, IIS7

- For IE 9/10 version it throws 'Object doesn't support property or method 'filter''
- It works fine for Firefox and chrome

2) If the application is hosted on Windows 8, IIS 8

- The code works for IE 9/10, Firefox and chrome

How come the hosting environment matters in order to make this code work?

Comment: What is `strs`? Show more relevant code, AJAX request, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, hope this helps others,

It was related to documentation mode where the client was using IE7 documentation mode on IE 10 browers. I had to add the following in web.config to make sure the client uses standard documentation mode.

```
<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```